# Is てもらう・てくださる the same thing as ご・おverbstemいただく・ください(but less formal)? What about ていだたけませんか etc（て constructions) then?

Tags: grammar, keigo

Is てもらう・てくださる the same thing as ご・おverbstemいただく・ください(but less formal)?
Example sentence:

> 安全にご使用いただくために下記の点にご注意願います。

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not the same.

下さい is a 命令形 (imperative inflection base) of 下さる (to give). In other words, 下さい is the same verb as 下さる only in a different form.

頂く（いただく）, to receive, is a humble counterpart of 貰う（もらう）.

御　(could be spelled and pronounced as お or ご) is an honorific prefix. 下さる is an honorific verb. In this sense both 御 and 下さる are in the same category (they are both used in the honorific context).

Answer (score 0):

安全にご使用いただくために下記の点にご注意願います。

Translation: 
Please note the following list In order i (merchant/company) can receive(いただく) you (customer) to use my product (merchant/ company) safely

Actually this sentence imply the merchant or company want to receive their customer to use their product safely .
あなた（お客様）が使用することを私がいただくことができる」

I think the idea is slightly the same. 
With ~ていただく／~てもらう, you are implicitly performing the action; you receive something. But ~ていただく is politer for example refer to customer,etc.

with ~くださる, the honoured subject is performing the action for you. someone above you such as your boss is doing something for you, less polite form is ~くれる
Such as 
when you tell the situation that your friend  do something for you.

But in “ご注意ください” has slightly different meaning, it is imperative.

The word “注意” with “ご” attached means It will be an expression of the act and respect for the partner. 
In addition, it becomes a polite expression of the meaning to ask "Please keep in mind, please take care” . 
There is a nuance that it keeps the consciousness of the opponent.